# 8 friends, 7 nights, invite 4 every night, all of the friends must be invited, how many options?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Assume I have 8 friends, I want to invite 4 friends each night for 7 night so everyone will be invited at least once. How many combinations are there to do it?

I think I'm supposed to use the *Inclusion & Exclusion theorem* but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The following is a crude Inclusion/Exclusion approach. Imagine choosing $4$ people to invite each night, paying no atention to who has been invited before.

There are $\dbinom{8}{4}^7$ ways to do this.

Now we want to take away the bad choices, in which one or more friend is left out $7$ times in a row.

There are $\dbinom{7}{4}^7$ choices in which Alicia is left out. Add up over all friends. That gives a total of $8\cdot \dbinom{7}{4}^7$.

But we have double counted, for example, the choices where **both** Alicia and Beti are left out. Continue in the usual Inclusion/Exclusion way.

Comment: I need to continue with the Inclusion Exclusion until I'm in a situation where 4 are left out right? Because below 4 there won't be enough friends to invite?

Comment: Is it wrong to choose who's not coming (= $8\choose1$) and then  choose 4 people that will come and spread them to 7 nights (= $7\choose4$$*4^7$)?

Comment: The answer to your first question is yes, there are not many terms. Something based on the second suggestion might work, but there is a lot of missing detail. For sure the Inclusion/Exclusion of the answer works.

Comment: So is this the answer?
${8\choose4}^7 - 8\times{7\choose4}^7 + 8\times{6\choose4}^7 - 8\times{5\choose4}^7 + 8\times{4\choose4}^7$ The multiply in 8 is there to count the 8 friends that can be uninvited right? I feel like something is missing when counting the situations where more than one friend is not invited, am I right?

Comment: The first $8$ (second term) is "really" $\binom{8}{1}$. The second should be $\binom{8}{2}$, the third $\binom{8}{3}$, the fourth $\binom{8}{4}$.

Comment: RIGHT! because you choose 1 who won't come from the 8, and then you choose 2 that won't come! Thank you!

Comment: When we remove $\binom{8}{1}\binom{7}{4}^7$, we removed twice the $\binom{6}{4}^7$ situations where A and B are never invited, so we must add it back in once. We must do this for each of the $\binom{8}{2}$ pairs of people. But then we have added in too much in the situations where, for example, none of A, B, or C are invited. To compensate for that, for all triples, is what the $-\binom{8}{3}\binom{5}{4}$ term does.